# Freemarker and line break white space

Tags: freemarker

I am using Freemarker to create an email template that contains a shipping address. In my my template I am using an <#if> statement that if address_2 or address_3 has content to print it - if not to not print anything in that line. The problem I am having is that I am getting a blank line break where that address would be and would like to avoid this.

I tried adding the <#compress> but that did not work. Is there an alternate way to do this?

My template below:

```
<#compress>
${transaction.custbody_company}
${transaction.custbody_address_1}
<#if transaction.custbody_address_2?has_content>${transaction.custbody_address_2}</#if> 
<#if transaction.custbody_address_3?has_content>${transaction.custbody_address_3}</#if>
${transaction.custbody_city_cda}, ${transaction.custbody_state_province} ${transaction.custbody_postal_code}
</#if>
</#compress>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the significant line break inside the `#if`:

```
<#if transaction.custbody_address_2?has_content>
${transaction.custbody_address_2}
</#if>
```

The line breaks after the lonely tags will be removed (see white-space tripping: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html#dgui_misc_whitespace_stripping).